# Pytesseract cannot recogonize all characters

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

Pytesseract cannot recogonize all characters in image

[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH0Yk.jpg)

The url of images https://sarathi.parivahan.gov.in/slots/Captcha.jpg

code i used

```s
rewww01_url = "https://sarathi.parivahan.gov.in:443/slots/Captcha.jpg"
rewww01_headers = {"Referer": "https://sarathi.parivahan.gov.in/slots/dlslotbook.do",
                   "Connection": "close"}
burp_req = s.get(rewww01_url, headers=rewww01_headers, stream=True)
with open('CAPTCHA.png', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(burp_req.raw, out_file)
del burp_req
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'
imu = 'CAPTCHA.png'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(imu), lang="eng")
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy ocr must give better results for your input capatcha. You can install easy ocr by `pip install easyocr`

[image]

The code

```
import easyocr

IMAGE_PATH = 'Captcha.jpg'
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext(IMAGE_PATH)
print(result)
```

the corrrsponding output is

```
[([[0, 0], [94, 0], [94, 28], [0, 28]], 'js4fxo', 0.9641285295055149)]
```